# HSQLDB Statement and Java NaN doubles

Tags: java, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I'm currently using HSQLDB to save java data. Within theses datas, there are some Double, and some of them can be of values of `NaN` (described as `0.0/0.0` in the javadoc). HSQLDB know how to handle these values in `setDouble` and `setFloat` of `PreparedStatement`. The thing is, I have to use a `Statement` object, not a precompiled stored procedure, and I just can't find a way to make it work.
If you had the tinyest hint, it would be most welcome :)
Thanks.

EDIT : Here's the bunch of code I'm using :

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Mesh(Id, name, dimension, meshtype, totalVolume, NumberOfCoarseCell) values (identity(), "  
                             + "'" + name_ + "',"  
                             + dimension_ + "," // this value can be NaN  
                             + "'" + type_.toString() + "',"   
                             + totalVolume_ + "," // this value can be NaN  
                             + numberOfCoarseCells_ + ")");
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a `Statement`? A `PreparedStatement` is **not** a "precompiled stored procedure", it's just a special kind of statement and usually the better choice anyway!

Comment: I need a Statement because I'm working in an already defined program and if I can't find a way to make it work with Statements, I would have to modify thousands of class... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HSQLDB 1.8.x you can use (0.0e1/0.0e1) as an expression that returns NaN.

For example:

```
create table t (d double)
insert into t values (0.0e1/0.0e1)
```

For HSQLDB 2.1 and above, an property must be specified with an SQL statement:

```
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN FALSE
```

Or as a connection property:

```
hsqldb.double_nan=false
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. I get a "division by 0" exeception when I try to use it the way you indicate.

Comment: Required property added to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You mean you need a way to write a NaN within a SQL statement? The following works for the [H2 database](http://h2database.com):

```
select sqrt(-1) from dual
```

However, it doesn't work for Apache Derby and PostgreSQL (I didn't test other databases). For HSQLDB, it no longer works in version 2.1 and newer, unless you set `SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN FALSE`.

Comment: HI and thx for for your answer.  When I try to use sqrt(-1), I get this message though : java.sql.SQLException: data exception: numeric value out of range? Any idea?

Comment: I actually works if I use sqrt(-1) in a console, but it doesn't seems to work within a Statement object actually. Any idea? Thx.

Comment: This no longer works in HSQLDB 2.5, unless (as in @fredt's answer), `SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN FALSE` is specified